# Как вызвать асинхронную функцию для телеграмм бота через сам код, а не через чат в телеграмме?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, async-await, асинхронность, asyncio

Имеется функция, которая повторяется каждые 3 секунды. В данной функции вызывается асинхронная функция, которая отправляет юзеру телеграмм сообщение. В итоге должно выйти так, чтобы каждые 3 секунды юзер получал сообщение, но в данном коде после отправки сообщения (сообщение само отправилось мне в личку, я его вижу), функция interview не завершается, тем самым не возвращается в функцию update и программа просто простаивает, не выдавая ошибок.

```
async def interview():
    await bot.send_message(1471718311, 'Тест')


def update():
    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    event_loop.run_until_complete(interview())
    event_loop.run_forever()
    threading.Timer(2, update).start()


update()
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
async def interview():
    await bot.send_message(1471718311, 'Тест')

def update():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    loop.create_task(interview())
    loop.call_later(2, update)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.call_soon(update)
loop.run_forever()
```

При запущенном loop асинхронные функции запускаются через [create_task](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.create_task).

Таймер можно заменить на строенный таймер эвент лупа через [call_later](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.call_later).

Чтоб первый апдейт был запущен на запущенном эвент лупе его проще всего запланировать через [call_soon](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.call_soon).

П.С. Вместо run_forever обычно должна быть функция запуска бота, которая запускает run_forever внутри себя, например, start_polling, если она присутствует в коде. Если нет - то run_forever.

П.П.С. Передать параметры в функцию можно через [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial)